# Flutter - How do I toggle the color of a RaisedButton upon click?

Tags: android, button, dart, widget, flutter

I am trying to toggle the color of a raised button. Initially the button should be blue and when it is pressed it turns to grey. Right now I have a bool value called pressAttention and it is set to false. I am using this to initially set this the false. When the button is pressed it toggles the pressAttention bool, but it seems that the widget is never updated again.

```
new RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text("Attention"),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  color: pressAttention?Colors.grey:Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () => doSomething("Attention"),
                )

void doSomething(String buttonName){
if(buttonName == "Attention"){
  if(pressAttention = false){
    pressAttention = true;
  } else {
    pressAttention = false;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you calling setState?

Comment: I do not believe so, I am pretty new to flutter and dart.

Comment: Flutter will only redraw things when you tell it something changed, one way to do so is with setState. I suggest you have a look at the tutorials on the website, e.g. https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This button will need to be created in the `build` of a `State` of a `StatefulWidget`, and the State must have a member variable `bool pressAttention = false;`. As Edman suggests, you need to make state changes in a `setState` callback for the Widget to redraw.

```
new RaisedButton(
  child: new Text('Attention'),
  textColor: Colors.white,
  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
  ),
  color: pressAttention ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
  onPressed: () => setState(() => pressAttention = !pressAttention),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the button to change color for the pressed state you just need to use the "highlightColor" property in RaisedButton

```
       RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("Test"),
          highlightColor: YOUR_PRESSED_COLOR, //Replace with actual colors
          color: IDLE_STATE_COLOR,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use rxdart:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

...

bool presssedFavorite = false;
final _pressAttention = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
Observable<bool> get coursesStream => _pressAttention.stream;

...

StreamBuilder(stream: _pressAttention,
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData)
  presssedFavorite = snapshot.data;

  return RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: (){
        _addToFavorites(context);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Icon(
          presssedFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 17,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),

void _addToFavorites(BuildContext context) async{
  //my code...
  _pressAttention.sink.add(!presssedFavorite);
}
```

It is more complicated, but you can use this solution also with web services, firestore, db... And you can use with StatelessWidget and StatefulWidget.