# Flutter - How do I toggle the color of a RaisedButton on click depending on the value of an if and else statement

Tags: flutter, button, dart

I am creating a logo quiz, and the color of the button shall change on press to green if the user choose the right answer or red otherwise. I have tried to solve this using this question [Flutter - How do I toggle the color of a RaisedButton upon click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863681/flutter-how-do-i-toggle-the-color-of-a-raisedbutton-upon-click) but it did not help much, the color would stay the same on press for the next question which is not what I am looking for. Please help.

```
var pressAttention = false;
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: 300.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text(
                          multiChoice[count][0],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            // checking if the user got the right answer
                            if (correctAnswer[count] == 0) {
                              correctAnswerCount++;
                              // do something to change the color of the button to green
                              // pressAttention = !pressAttention
                            }else{
                              // do something to change the color of the button to red
                            }
                          });
                          nextQuestion();
                        },
                        highlightColor: pressAttention ? Colors.green : Colors.red, //changing to green or red depending on the if and else statement,
                        hoverColor: pressAttention ? Colors.green : Colors.red, //changing to green or red depending on the if and else statement,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to store the answers, and check if the answer matches the users answer. If it does then set the color only.

Set the color when the user changes question or answers the question.

Comment: Yeah I have already the list  I need to understand how the pressAttention variable can be used to toggle the color if the correct answer is clicked or not, that is my main issue