# Color change of button by pressing it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

how can i change color of these iconbuttons by pressing it, please help me and show me whole code for it,
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is new method to change color,
there is `youtube` video for this [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDmGGi_RlDM) and a article for this  [Article](https://flutterforyou.com/change-elevated-button-color-on-press-in-flutter/)

```
ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Elevated Button'),
          onPressed: () {
            print('Pressed');
          },
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return Colors.green;
                return Colors.greenAccent;
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
```

You can change the `background color` of the `ElevatedButton` using `MaterialStateProperty class`. You can change the color of the button based on the states too. See the code snippet given below.

Comment: This is only for knowledge purpose

Answer (score 1):

In setState you have to add boolean variable, for example changeColor = false;

Then in button :

```
color: changeColor ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
  onPressed: () => setState(() => changeColor = !changeColor),
```

[Flutter - How do I toggle the color of a RaisedButton upon click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863681/flutter-how-do-i-toggle-the-color-of-a-raisedbutton-upon-click)

Answer (score 0):

IconButton in flutter has a `color` variable you can set as here:

```
  IconButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I would use:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            const Text(
              'Choose Category',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            Row(children: [
              CategoryButton(
                svg: 'assets/candy.svg',
                label: 'Tech',
                selected: false,
              ),
              CategoryButton(
                svg: 'assets/candy.svg',
                label: 'Finance',
                selected: false,
              ),
              CategoryButton(
                svg: 'assets/candy.svg',
                label: 'Design',
                selected: false,
              ),
              CategoryButton(
                svg: 'assets/candy.svg',
                label: 'File',
                selected: false,
              ),
              CategoryButton(
                svg: 'assets/candy.svg',
                label: 'Music',
                selected: false,
              ),
            ])
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryButton extends StatefulWidget {
  CategoryButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.svg,
    required this.label,
    required this.selected,
  }) : super(key: key);
  String svg;
  String label;
  bool selected;
  @override
  State<CategoryButton> createState() => _CategoryButtonState();
}

class _CategoryButtonState extends State<CategoryButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.selected = !widget.selected;
        });
        print(widget.selected);
      },
      child: Container(
          height: 40,
          width: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.selected ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(widget.svg,
                  color: widget.selected ? Colors.white : Colors.blue),
              Text(
                widget.label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 9,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

here you need to make sure to add flutter_svg to your pubspec.yaml file and have a folder for your assets and add that to your pubspec.yaml file as well

if you have any further questions just ask :)